# SyntaxError: invalid syntax during launching move_it

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey i'm new in ROS. I've been tried to launch moveit!
`roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch`
i'd got these error "**SyntaxError: invalid syntax** ". These are my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/bin/roslaunch", line 34, in <module>
    import roslaunch
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from .scriptapi import ROSLaunch
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/scriptapi.py", line 42, in <module>
    import roslaunch.parent
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 54, in <module>
    import roslaunch.server
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/server.py", line 79, in <module>
    from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Log
  File "/opt/ros/dashing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rosgraph_msgs/msg/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from rosgraph_msgs.msg._clock import Clock  # noqa: F401
  File "/opt/ros/dashing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rosgraph_msgs/msg/_clock.py", line 56
    class Clock(metaclass = Metaclass_Clock):
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And these might be related error but i've feel doesn't help :https://answers.ros.org/question/221035/ros-scripts-and-python-related-error/
Please I need help, and anybody have suggestion ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346943/syntaxerror:-invalid-syntax-during-launching-move_it/) by [Augustine_Sena](https://answers.ros.org/users/52620/augustine_sena/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We see this:

```
File "/opt/ros/melodic/bin/roslaunch",
```

and:

```
File "/opt/ros/dashing/lib/python3.6
```

which suggests you have both ROS 1 Melodic and ROS 2 Dashing installed on your machine.

Moreover, you probably also have both ROS versions `source`d in the same shell. Do you have two `source /opt/ros/.../setup.bash` lines in your `.bashrc` by any chance?

If so, remove the one for ROS 2 for now and see whether things start working.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is probably because you are running ROS under python 2.7 and in your code you are using Python 3 syntax for metaclass definition. So i would say there is a mixure of Python versions.

---

Originally posted by [sbambula](https://answers.ros.org/users/51982/sbambula/) with karma: 11 on 2020-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-18**:
The traceback makes reference to ROS Dashing, which is a ROS 2 version which makes use of Python 3. So that would be expected.

What the OP needs to do is sort out in which order he `source`s things, and/or whether he even needs to `source` both ROS versions at the same time.